# What kind of shapes can wands have?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

I was wondering, does a wand have to be in only the shape of a cylinder with a smooth narrowed tip?

Can it have a bent shape or have two ends like a two blade fork? Can it be flat or have a snake-like shape? Would any other shape be impossible for a wand to work?

For instance, if Ollivander makes a four-faced (square) wand with a flattened tip, would it work?

P.s. What about scepters or scepter-like shapes?

Comment: Australian wands are shaped like boomerangs.

Answer (score 8):

## In the movies, they absolutely can be different shapes.

There are a lot of different wand shapes seen in the movies, they’re definitely not just all cylinders. We never see any with a forked end on the side that’s aimed to cast spells, and that might not be possible since wands are intended to channel magic through, and having two separate parts would make it harder to target where the spell hits. With that likely exception, there are a lot of possible shapes wands can be.

Bellatrix’s wand has a bent, curved shape.

[image]

Lucius’s wand has a snake head, and it fits into his cane.

[image]

Pettigrew has a wavy wand that looks somewhat like a rat tail.

[image]

Dolores Umbridge has a bumpy wand that looks like connecting spheres, with a pink crystal in the middle.

[image]

Slughorn’s wand has two separate little parts at the end he’d hold, like a slug’s antennae.

[image]

## In the books, it’s never stated.

Other than sometimes the wand cores, lengths, and woods, what the wands themselves look like isn’t described much in the books. There aren’t detailed descriptions of what anyone’s wand looks like, so what range of shapes the wands in the books can be is unknown.

Comment: Pettigrew's wand is all wiggly

Comment: @Valorum Thanks so much! :) I’ll add it in!

Comment: the snake on Lucius's wand is the part he holds. like the handle of a knife. It seems like it also fits into his walking stick which acts as a sort of sheaf.
Considering that wands are intended to channel magic, I suspect they may not be perfectly smooth, but straight. it would be like having a crooked gun.

Comment: Upvoted already, but what about adding a paragraph about the wands as depicted on [Pottermore](https://my.pottermore.com/user-profile/wand) (which could have had some input from JKR)?

Comment: [Pottermore (not JKR) page](https://www.pottermore.com/features/designing-harry-potter-wands) about the wands in the movies, with nice images; the _"Page to screen"_ book could have more info and images.

Comment: 'Lucius’s wand has a snake head, and it fits into his cane.' Wrong. It's purely decoration, as seen when Voldemort removes it.